# pass test spec to another test spec

Tags: testing, mocha.js, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

How would I pass one test spec to another as to continue a flow. For example say I have a success login spec, that logs into my site and says returns whether it pass. How could I pass that spec to a spec that tests my checkout process which requires you to be logged in? I'm using Mocha, and Webdriver.IO to run the tests

i have a spec as such

```
var LoginPage = require('../pageObjects/login.page');

describe('login form', function () {

  it('page title should be Sign In', function () {
    LoginPage.open();
    var title = LoginPage.title();
    expect(title).to.contain('Sign In');
  })

  it('should grant access with creds', function () {
    LoginPage.open();
    LoginPage.username.setValue('ygtest2@mailinator.com');
    LoginPage.password.setValue('11111111');
    LoginPage.submit();
    var title = LoginPage.title()
    expect(title).to.contain('Your username is invalid!');
  });
});
```

I would like to call this spec in another spec.

Comment: You don't pass the spec, you extract the shared logic into a helper function or method (see the *"page object"* paradigm, for example).

Comment: do you mean page object as described here? http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html I am using this paradigm to remove the actual getting of html elements in my scripts, but that doesn't answer my question of how I should transfer the signed in application state between tests.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to pass any spec. What you need to do is use mocha hooks as described [here](https://mochajs.org/)

You'll have to write login and access spec in a

```
before(function() {
    // runs before all tests in this block
  });
```

or

```
beforeEach(function() {
    // runs before each test in this block
  });
```

depending on your need. If you use `before(function()` , that code will run before all `its` , If you use `beforeEach(function()` , it will run before each `its` within your `describe`